# Compile template containing Partial

Tags: javascript, templates, dust.js, dustc

I have a dustjs template heirarchy like so:

**layout.dust**

```
...
{> "book/BookListings" /}
...
```

Then, **BookListings.dust**:

```
{#books}
{> "templates/OneBook" /}
{/books}
```

I have several books to display in BookListings. For every Book, I use `OneBook` template. It all works fine when I run it for the first time.

Problem arises when I try to reuse the **compiled template** on the front-end in a Single Page App mode.

I use `dustc` to compile `BookListings` template using the command:

`dustc BookListings.dust BookListings.js`

On the front end, when I try to load the template, I get the error:

> Dust Error:  Error {stack: (...), message: "Template Not Found:
>   templates/OneBook"}

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiling a template does not compile its partials together with it.

You would still need to compile the `OneBook` template and include it on the page at runtime so it will be registered.

You can use the `--name` flag to tell the compiler that the template should be named `templates/OneBook` (this is just a name, even though it looks like a path).